# How to export sqlite into CSV using RSqlite?

Tags: csv

How to export sqlite into CSV using RSqlite?
I am asking because I am not familiar with database files, so I want to convert it using R.
It may be very simple, but I haven't figure out.

Answer (score 1):

not quite sure if you have figured this out. I am not quite sure how to do it within R either but it seems pretty simple to export to csv using SQLite itself, or by writing out csv from the database you have loaded to R.

In SQLite, you can do something like this at your command prompt

```
>.mode csv
>.export output.csv
>.header on
>select * from table_name;
>.exit
```

SQLite will automatically wrote out your table to a output.csv file

Answer (score 1):

If the table is not too large, you can first export it into an data frame or matrix in R using the dbGetQuery or the dbSendQuery and fetch commands. Then, you can write that data frame as a .csv file.

```
my.data.frame <- dbGetQuery(My_conn, "SELECT * FROM My_Table")
write.csv(my.data.frame, file = "MyFileName.csv", ...)
```